# Failed to download Package list, Report this to developers

Tags: package-management

im am unable to install new packages and updates, i get an error as shown below, pls help[image: .]
[image: .]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks more like a typo in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cscarney-unity-web-place-oneriric.list

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cscarney-unity-web-place-oneriric.list
```

I believe the lines should look like this

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cscarney/unity-web-place/ubuntu oneiric main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cscarney/unity-web-place/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Comment: Yes, probably you have `ain` instead of `main`.

Comment: how can i correct it?